# VBA compare Abs() values not working

Tags: arrays, vba, compare, decimal

I have two arrays of data where I want to compare every element in both arrays and put the biggest absolute value in an new array. See code below:

```
If Abs(DataArray1(i)) < Abs(DataArray2(i)) Then
     NewDataArray(i) = DataArray2(i)
Else
     NewDataArray(i) = DataMinArray(i)
End If
```

The probem is that some of the values are decimals and if I compare for example -1.02 and 1.0100 then normaly -1.02 has bigger abs value. In my case my program returns 1.0100 and it happens to all values are not the same length. The longer one is always returned. How could that happen and what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

are the arrays of String type? Otherwise i couldn't explain why values like 1.0100 even exist. That value should automatically be shown as 1.01

If you are working with Strings then try to convert the values to floats. This could work: `Abs(CDbl(DataArray1(i))) < Abs(CDbl(DataArray2(i)))`

Comment: Well that was an bad example I gave but yes I realised that they are Strings. I tried to converting to Double as you said but then for some reason I lose the dot so 1.234 becomes 1234. How do I solve that?

Comment: Maybe you need a different decimal separator. That depends on what country settings are set on your machine. For example in Germany we use a comma as decimal separator. So you would have to use `Abs(CDbl(Replace(DataArray1(i), ".", ","))) < Abs(CDbl(Replace(DataArray2(i), ".", ",")))`

Comment: That did the job, simple as that. Thank you!!